# Следует ли ставить запятую? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**В первом варианте гимна Аполлону(,) он предстает как блюститель, требующий правды, справедливости, оградитель от несчастий, податель благ.**

Следует ли ставить запятую после «Аполлону»?

Answer (score 2):

Вот что пишет Розенталь.
Для смыслового выделения или для попутного пояснения могут обособляться обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами), особенно если при этих существительных имеются пояснительные слова.
Чаще всего такие конструкции образуются существительными с предлогами или предложными сочетаниями (*благодаря, в зависимости, в отличие, в связи с, вследствие, несмотря на, при условии, согласно* и др.).
[§ 20.Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827488.html)

*Предстает* (где?) *в первом варианте гимна Аполлону.*

Оборот (я бы не назвала его "глобально" распространенным) стоит в начале предложения — непосредственно перед подлежащим и сказуемым (не разделяет их); никаких добавочных оттенков значения не имеет (то есть дополнительную смысловую нагрузку не несет); производных предлогов в нем нет — это причины, по которым **не следует** ставить указанную запятую.

Вот похожее предложение — без запятой.
*На первом варианте первой строки «Свободных народов союз благородный» Сталин делает пометку...*

Answer (score 1):

***В первом варианте гимна Аполлону*** он предстает как блюститель, требующий правды, справедливости, оградитель от несчастий, податель благ.

Обстоятельственный оборот, выраженный **падежной формой существительного**, **в начале предложения** не обособляется.

Такой оборот входит в основной состав предложения, нет ни семантических, ни грамматических  причин для его обособления.